# How do I find a specific color and ask the position, width and height of it

Tags: c#, colors, 360-degrees

**Hey guys.**

Is it possible for me, for example, to have a picture in Photoshop and have made a black surface in it so that Unity can find that specific black surface and request its location, width and height from it.

I would like to make my app automatic. What I mean by that is that if people make a 360 skydome with a few black areas in it, I can say in code that Unity has to find those black areas and then has to put a movie there.

Who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

if I understand right , you want to get the position of the specific color and width and height . i did it before with aspose and template here is my code , I hope help you

```
public static void CheckRotation(string imageFilePath, string templateFilePath, int tryCount)
    {
      if (tryCount > 2)
        throw new Exception("the Image Cant be Detected");

      int leftTotal = 0;
      int leftBlackColor = 0;

      int rightTotal = 0;
      int rightBlackColor = 0;

      byte findLeftAndRight = 0;

      OmrTemplate template = OmrTemplate.Load(templateFilePath);
      OmrImage image = OmrImage.Load(imageFilePath);
      OmrEngine engine = new OmrEngine(template);
      image.AutoDetectResolution = true;

      OmrProcessingResult result = engine.ExtractData(new OmrImage[] { image });
      Hashtable OmrResult = result.PageData[0];
      ICollection key = OmrResult.Keys;

      OmrElementsCollection collection = template.Pages[0].Elements;
      foreach (Object obj in collection)
      {
        if (obj.GetType() == typeof(ChoiceBoxElement))
        {
          var elem = (ChoiceBoxElement)obj;

          if (elem.Name.ToString().ToUpper() == "LEFT" || elem.Name.ToString().ToUpper() == "RIGHT")
          {
            findLeftAndRight++;

            var xPosition = int.Parse(Math.Floor((elem.Position.X * 150) / 25.4).ToString()) + 1;
            var yPosition = int.Parse(Math.Floor((elem.Position.Y * 150) / 25.4).ToString()) + 1;

            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(imageFilePath);
            BitmapData data = bitmap.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(xPosition, yPosition, int.Parse(Math.Floor((elem.Size.Width * 150) / 25.4).ToString()), int.Parse(Math.Floor((elem.Size.Height * 150) / 25.4).ToString())),
            ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);  // make sure you check the pixel format as you will be looking directly at memory

            unsafe
            {
              // example assumes 24bpp image.  You need to verify your pixel depth
              // loop by row for better data locality
              for (int y = 0; y < data.Height; ++y)
              {
                byte* pRow = (byte*)data.Scan0 + y * data.Stride;
                for (int x = 0; x < data.Width; ++x)
                {
                  // windows stores images in BGR pixel order
                  byte r = pRow[2];
                  byte g = pRow[1];
                  byte b = pRow[0];

                  if (elem.Name.ToString().ToUpper() == "LEFT")
                    leftTotal++;
                  else if (elem.Name.ToString().ToUpper() == "RIGHT")
                    rightTotal++;

                  if (
                      (r == 0 && g == 0 && b == 0) ||
                      ((r < 100 && g < 100) || (r < 100 && b < 100) || (b < 100 && g < 100)) ||
                      (r < 120 && g < 120 && b < 120 && Math.Abs(r - g) < 10 && Math.Abs(r - b) < 10 && Math.Abs(b - g) < 10)
                    )
                  {
                    if (elem.Name.ToString().ToUpper() == "LEFT")
                      leftBlackColor++;
                    else if (elem.Name.ToString().ToUpper() == "RIGHT")
                      rightBlackColor++;
                  }


                  // next pixel in the row
                  pRow += 3;
                }
              }
            }

            bitmap.UnlockBits(data);
          }
        }
      }

      if (findLeftAndRight != 2)
        throw new Exception("The Left and Right Mark Didnt Exists!!");

      var leftPercentage = (leftBlackColor / leftTotal) * 100;
      var rightPercentage = (rightBlackColor / rightTotal) * 100;

      if (leftPercentage > 80 && rightPercentage > 80) //It means The Paper is Currect Rotation
        return;
      else
      {
        RotateImage(imageFilePath, 180);
        CheckRotation(imageFilePath, templateFilePath, ++tryCount);
      }


    }
```

Comment: Do you have the variables for me. I get now tons of errors

Comment: do you have aspose  dll?first you have to get these dlls. Aspose Site : https://www.aspose.com/?gclid=CjwKCAjwuO3cBRAyEiwAzOxKsjvq8QSp0HN3GPleV2FcH3GH_WcSl32UQhPo_GPrH5abPPjvfx-i1BoC0r8QAvD_BwE

Comment: Can you give me a specefic link so I can donwload it directly?

Comment: Can you tell me in steps what do I have to do. I am new to this sorry =D